# SelectedValue & SelectedItem From Drop Down List

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am attempting to write the selected values to two separate text boxes named `this.txtTextSelected.Text = text;` and `this.txtValueSelected.Text = value;`

My issue is that the values are not written to the two text boxes, and when an option is selected my page refreshes and doesn't actually store the selected value which makes me think 
1) Either my HTML for the drop down list is incorrect
2) I have added un-needed syntax for something
But I am scratching my head as to what the real deal is.

**This is my HTML for the drop down list**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownlist1" CssClass="DropDownLists" 
runat="server" Width="90px"
AutoPostBack="true" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**And this is my C# code behind for the page**

```
protected void dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value = dropdownlist1.SelectedValue;
    string text = dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Text;
    this.txtValueSelected.Text = value;
    this.txtTextSelected.Text = text;
}
```

**EDIT**
Will this remedy my problem (basing this off @David comment below)

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    BindDropDownList();
}
```

Comment: A common error is that your `Page_Load` code may be clobbering the values before you try to use them.  Are you re-binding the `DropDownList` and/or re-clearing the `TextBox`es in `Page_Load`?

Comment: @David - I am not clearing the DropDownList on Page Load but I am re-binding them on Page_Load.

Comment: `Page_Load` runs before any event handler.  So if you're re-binding the `DropDownList` on every post-back then there won't be a selected value to use when the event handler runs.

Comment: @David --- see my edit, will that remedy my situation?

Comment: It should, give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(In response to comments and the question edit...)

Unlike WinForms, WebForms "form" objects don't persist in memory.  Web applications are designed to be inherently stateless.  So *every* request results in re-instantiating the targeted form object, which invokes all of the start-up stuff that happens in a form.

This includes `Page_Load`.

So any time you click a button or do anything that involves posting the page back to the server, `Page_Load` (and other initialization events) happen again, *before* any event handlers or custom logic.

This means that if you're binding your controls in `Page_Load`, you're going to re-bind them before you try to use them.  In WebForms, the standard fix for this is to wrap them in a conditional when binding:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    // bind your controls
}
```

This will bind the controls when initially loading a page, but not when re-submitting the page's form to the page (posting back).

Comment: Thank you for that!  I 99% of the time use winforms which I am learning is a WORLD of difference between winforms and webforms.

Comment: @RashidAbib: It is a significant difference indeed.  I've often been known to say, "WebForms is a lie."  It was, at the time, a *great* way to bring WinForms developers to the web.  But you're going to find it a *lot* easier if you think of it in terms of web architecture with WinForms layered on top of it rather than a direct port of WinForms.  The more you can understand the structure of HTTP requests and responses and how a stateless request/response system is meant to work, the better you'll be able to manage WebForms.